# Selling BTC and claiming forks, what should be done first?

Tags: blockchain-fork, cross-chain-recovery

I own some small amount of BTC since 2015. As I was busy doing an offline business, I absolutely missed all information updates about BTC for latest 7 years. Now I am going to sell my BTC but I discovered that there is such a thing as "forks" and I can claim and get them.
Can you please explain me with as simple words as possible:

Do forks "belong" to my BTC or do they "belong" to my wallet?
Thus, if I sell my BTC tomorrow, can I still claim all forks later?
Or is it so that when I send BTC to another wallet, then I am authomatically sending all forks to that wallet?
Should I first claim forks and then sell BTC, or can I first sell BTC and then claim forks?
I shall be grateful for your answer!
Please explain like for a kid, without complicated technical words  :-)
Thank you very much!

Comment: @Murch I'm not sure the tag [tag:cross-chain-recovery] is appropriate here, shouldn't it be [tag:airdrop]?

Comment: @VojtěchStrnad: I figured that perusing the [tag:cross-chain-recovery] tag would benefit the asker or other interested parties, because this is also about trying to use keys originally created for one network to spend funds on another. You're right though that it's not an exact fit, and I don't have a strong opinion that the tag needs to be there. I'd be happy if you added airdrop or replace cross-chain-recovery with airdrop.

Answer (score 1):

Especially 2017 saw the creation of a plethora of forkcoins—altcoins that used the current state of the Bitcoin network as a starting point. Generally, the UTXOs on those networks are locked to the same keys as your original BTC. This means that you will not see them in your Bitcoin wallet, but you will be able to access them by using the same private keys.

1. Make notes which addresses hold funds.
2. Your bitcoins will be by far the most valuable asset overall. Some of the altcoin software may be unsafe or malicious, so your priority should be to first ensure that even if the private keys of your original wallet get compromised by an attacker, the bitcoins are already safe: Create a new wallet, properly back it up, and send your bitcoins there. Since you mentioned that you aim to sell, you could also deposit your bitcoins directly into the service that you want to use to sell them. Bitcoin transactions are not replayable to any of the main Bitcoin forkcoins (as of 2022-10).
3. (Optional) Use the list of addresses from above to export the corresponding private keys from Bitcoin Core to create a handy list of relevant private keys.
4. After your bitcoins are safely removed from the original wallet, you'll need wallet software that works for the fork coin networks.
   A simple way to get started might be to import the private keys with balances into a multicoin wallet such as e.g. Exodus, which seems to support Bitcoin Cash, Bitcoin SV, and Bitcoin Gold out of the box  and lists accessing fork coins as one of its use-cases.
   Alternatively, you can download wallets for each coin specifically and import your wallet backup into them. Go one-by-one and start with the most valuable forks: Bitcoin Cash (BCH), Bitcoin SV (BSV), eCash (XEC), and Bitcoin Gold (BTG). Don't get too excited, even these four are today in sum worth less than 1% of BTC. After that the value trails off quickly, but a cursory search finds me longer lists of Bitcoin forks (there were some 70+ created in 2017 IIRC).

Comment: "Bitcoin transactions are not replayable to any of the main Bitcoin forkcoins" just two months after the ursf discussion? How sure this sentence can age well?